# Open source mp4 player

Tags: open-source, mp4

Can you suggest an open source project dealing with playing "just" mp4? I don't want to have many available codec embedded in, just mp4 is adequate.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/), but you probably know it and ruled it out by now.
Using Google brought up [this list](http://www.dmoz.org//Computers/Multimedia/Music_and_Audio/Audio_Formats/MPEG-4/Software//).

Comment: Yes I know VLC. Thx for the list, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org), aka "the reference". (it has a little tool called 'ffplay' which is what you are after).

Answer (score -1):

other that "just" mp4, [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) fits your bill perfectly.

Comment: As I said it should be very small subset